# How to bind to `keydown` of another element in a directive

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I'm writing a directive for validation that accepts the name of an element in a form and prints error messages based on the value of the element.

This is an example ([live demo link here](http://jsbin.com/joseyu/1/edit?html,js,output))

```
  <form name="form" >
    <input type="text" name="inp" ng-model="myval" ng-minlength="3">
    <oversee watched="form.inp">
  </form>
```

The directive:

```
directive("oversee",function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      watched: '='
    },
    template: '<div ng-show="watched.$invalid">Error</div>',
    link: function (scope, elm) {
      console.log(scope.watched);
    }
  };
}
```

Here's the thing.
I want to change the error message to reflect the current length of the `input` element it is watching. (Like how Stackoverflow does in comments)

`5 more to go...`

So I have to bind to the element and get it's value on every `keyup`

*Notice* - I can't use: `{{myval.length}}` for this because the model is not updated while the form/input is invalid.

Hope I made my question clear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working [example](http://jsbin.com/biqazoruniya/2/edit), you can use $viewValue instead of model
note: you also need to take care of form error messages

```
angular.module("angtemp", [])
.controller("first", firstCtrl)
.directive("oversee",function () {
  var LIMIT = 20;
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      watched: '=',
      val: '='
    },
    template: '<div ng-show="countToType">{{countToType}} more to go...</div>',
    link: function (scope, elm) {      
      scope.$watch('val',function(newVal,oldVal){      
        if(!newVal) return;
        scope.countToType = LIMIT-newVal.length;

      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Bonus Question - Is there a way to get the attribute value of `ng-minlength` for the element being watched?

Comment: I think you can grab it with form.inp. and something extra, but im not sure, we need to look

Comment: seem its not possible, but why you need it ?

Comment: So I can write, for example: "3 chars to go", I need to calculate `(minlength - watched.length)`
`minlength` is the attribute `ng-minlength`

Comment: in worst way you can select input element by in directive link function document.getElementById and fetch id from DOM

Comment: What I did was to take the 'watched' attribute and  use it to take the element from the '$document' object (since an element `b` on form `a` will be accessible through `document.a.b`)